# Java - How to break a long statement

Tags: java

How do I break a long line of code like this into several lines in Java?

```
System.out.println("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy tex")
```

Comment: use IDE and format this statement

Comment: Sorry, I mean in the editor. I'm using TextWrangler, and my program is wider than the screen.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: are you seriously suggesting to download a full IDE just for format a line of String? You must be joking right?

Comment: Not just for this purpose, IDEs are better to use than simple text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
System.out.println("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing" +  
                    "and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been " + 
                    "the industry's standard dummy tex");
```

The resultant `String` will be the same as the original at the bytecode level

Answer (score 3):

have you tried this?

```
System.out.println("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"
                   + " of the printing and typesetting industry. "
                   + "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's "
                   + "standard dummy tex");
```

Answer (score 1):

use String concatination, like

```
System.out.println("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry." +
        " Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy tex");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
System.out.println("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and" + 
" typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's" +
" standard dummy tex")
```

Use "+" to concatenate two string which lives in two different lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can also apply line breaks- and either do it with more than a single command, like Rei did - but with a `print` on each part and the final one will be `println`, or use the `\n` special character:

```
System.out.println("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing\n" +  
                "and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been\n " + 
                "the industry's standard dummy tex");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:`System.out.println("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the "+
"printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's "+
"standard dummy tex");`

Answer (score 1):

**If you have String as :**

```
System.out.println("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy tex");
```

**Than you can do it this vay :**

```
System.out.println("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."  
                  +"Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy tex");
```

**Or you can split your String:**
Add any character where you want to split String or use some char that is already in String.

```
String string1 = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.-Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy tex";

String[] parts = string1.split("-");
String part0 = parts[0]; // Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
String part1 = parts[1]; //Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy tex
System.out.println(part0);
```

**output:** Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

**Note :** if you want to split by **"."** , it stands for every character so

**instead of**

> split(".");

**use**

> split("\\.");

**or**

> split(Pattern.quote("."));

To test beforehand if the string contains a -, just use

> String#contains()

```
if (string.contains("-")) {
    // Split it. 
} 
else {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("String " + string1 + " does not contain-"); 
 }
```

Comment: Nice going there, fully explained detail solution that invites him to learn more. +1